# Smooth convex function with unique minimizer is not strictly convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, maxima-minima, smooth-functions

Is smooth convex function with unique minimizer strictly convex? Here the strictly convexity of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ means

$$f((1-\lambda)x+\lambda y)<(1-\lambda)f(x)+\lambda f(y)\text{ for all }x\ne y,\lambda\in (0,1).$$

Without the smooth assumption, function $f(x)=|x|$ is an immediate counterexample. However, with the smoothness, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: If you know a function $f$ that is smooth and has several minimizers while still being strictly convex at one point $x$, then $g:y\to f(y)-\nabla f(x)^T y$ is a counter example. I think I had seen that such a function exists but I cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Good question! Another counterexample would be the [Huber loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss).

Comment: This works if the author is happy with $C^1$. But the Huber loss is not $C^2$.

Comment: That is correct. In optimization, "smooth" often means the [gradient exists and Lipschitz-continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860081/smoothness-means-that-the-gradient-is-lipschitz-continuous). For different definitions of "smooth", you'll need another counterexample.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Yes, I am happy with the answer, as in my mind, smooth means only $C^1$

Comment: It is interesting that the Huber function is not strictly convex globally, but it is still locally strictly convex around the minimizer $0$. By the way, the answer is good to me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: in this answer, 'smooth' refers to $C^{\infty}$.

We can find a counterexample in dimension $n=1$ by taking $x \mapsto |x|$ and smoothing it out in a particular way.
Take a smooth function $\rho \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,1]$ with the following properties: (i) $\rho$ is constantly equal to 1 inside the interval $[-0.5,0.5]$ and constantly equal to 0 outside of the interval $[-1,1]$; (ii) $\rho$ is increasing on the interval $(-\infty,0)$ and decreasing on the interval $(0,\infty)$; (iii) $\rho$ is convex on $(-\infty,-0.75) \cup (0.75,\infty)$ and concave on $(-0.75,0.75)$.
For the existence of such a function, see Wikipedia [1].

Now define $f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f(x)
= x^2 \rho(x) - \frac{9}{16} \rho(x) + 4 \int_0^{|x|} (1-\rho(y)) dy.
$$
Then $f$ is smooth despite the appearance of $|x|$ in the integral because of (i).
Also by (i), for $|x| > 1$,
$$
f(x)
= 4 |x| - 4 \int_0^1 \rho(y) dy,
$$
so $f$ is not strictly convex.
The derivative of $f$ is
$$
f'(x)
= 2 x \rho(x) + x^2 \rho'(x) - \frac{9}{16} \rho'(x) + 4 \mathrm{sign}(x) (1-\rho(|x|)).
$$
The second derivative of $f$ is
$$
f''(x)
= 2 \rho(x) + 2 x \rho'(x) + 2 x \rho'(x) + x^2 \rho''(x) - \frac{9}{16} \rho''(x) - 4 \rho'(|x|).
$$
Note that $x\rho'(x) = -|x\rho'(x)|$ and $\rho'(|x|) = -|\rho'(x)|$ by (ii).
Thus,
$$
f''(x)
= 2 \rho(x) + \left( x^2 - \frac{9}{16} \right) \rho''(x) + 4 |\rho'(x)| (1 - |x|).
$$
The first term $2 \rho(x)$ is always nonnegative as $\rho$ takes values in $[0,1]$.
The last term $4 |\rho'(x)| (1 - |x|)$ is always nonnegative by (i).
The second term $\left( x^2 - \frac{9}{16} \right) \rho''(x)$ is always nonnegative by (iii).
Thus, $f''$ is always nonnegative, which shows that $f$ is convex.
Finally, $f$ has a unique minimizer at 0 because it is strictly convex in a neighbourhood of 0, which follows from $f(x) = x^2 - 9/16$ for $|x| < 0.5$.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function